# hiphop, nginx, spdy

Tags: 12.04, google-chrome, php, nginx, ssl

I'm about a month young at linux and brand new to ubuntu.

I can do this to install hiphop https://github.com/facebook/hiphop-php/wiki/Building-and-installing-HHVM-on-Ubuntu-12.04

(I installed JEMalloc 3.0 b/c it was there)

But I'm not too sure how to install nginx with these options https://github.com/facebook/hiphop-php/wiki/Using-nginx-as-front-server-to-HipHop with spdy http://nginx.org/patches/spdy/README.txt.

Can anyone show me how to combine those two nginx installs with a self-signed cert and a purchased?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

those instructions are missing so much stuff.

you gotta setup `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in `/etc/environment`

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib:/usr/lib:/lib
```

download all those libs into `/usr/local/src`

set `prefix` not to `$CMAKE` whatever is there but to `/usr/local`

and compile with CLANG / LLVM goes much faster.

of course you gotta setup those too in `/etc/environment`

```
LD=/usr/bin/llvm-ld
CC=/usr/bin/clang
CXX=/usr/bin/clang++
CPP=/usr/bin/clang -E
```

Comment: you mind providing a detailed step by step?  i don't care anymore as i've moved on to fastcgi++/websocket++ (which i totally recommend), but i think there might be others, so i'll give check for details.  then again, considering the views & votes on this q, looks like hiphop might not be catching on